# name 'field_name' is not defined error while querying the db

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to query a foreign key attribute i am getting error as name 'field_name' is not defined

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(field_name)
```

Comment: It makes no sense to say `filter(field_name)`, how do you want to filter that field?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have a other field in the model that is related to foreignkey model i need to check that whether its null

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to say `filter(field_name)`: a filter means that a field is the same, less than, contains, etc. some value, or the value of some other field.

You can for example filter with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field_name=some_value)
```

or check if it is not null with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field_name__isnull=False)
```

if `field_name` is a `ForeignKey`, we will thus only retain `MyModel`s where the `ForeignKey` does *not* point to `None`/`NULL`.

Comment: Mymodel.objects.filter(field_name__foreignkeyfield__isnull = False) This worked